# How can i configure enqueue/enqueue-bundle/enqueue/amqp-ext to create queue and exchange

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq, symfony4, symfony-messenger

Im working with `symfony 4.3`, I have a problem with `enqueue/enqueue-bundle` and `enqueue/amqp-ext` implementation.
I always work with `php-amqplib`/`rabbitmq-bundle`, I use config file to create queue, exchange and binding ...

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:               "%rabbitmq_default_host%"
            port:               "%rabbitmq_default_port%"
            user:               "%rabbitmq_default_user%"
            password:           "%rabbitmq_default_password%"
            vhost:              "%rabbitmq_default_vhost%"
            lazy:               "%rabbitmq_default_lazy%"
            connection_timeout: "%rabbitmq_default_connection_timeout%"
            read_write_timeout: "%rabbitmq_default_read_write_timeout%"
            keepalive: "%rabbitmq_default_keepalive%"
            heartbeat: "%rabbitmq_default_heartbeat%"
    producers:
        sync_data:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: "my_exchange", type: topic}
    consumers:
        sync_data:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: "my_exchange", type: topic}
            queue_options:    {name: "my_queue", routing_keys: {'my.binding.#'}}
```

When i launch the consumer with `old_sound_rabbit_mq`, it will automatically create an exchange `my_exchange` with `topic` type, and it will also create `my_queue` with binding key `my.binding.#`
I want to make the same thing with `enqueue-bundle`, Can i do this ?

Comment: Did you run php bin/console enqueue:consume --setup-broker -vvv  ?

Consider using messenger component of symfony instead bundles, it's more powerful and reliable.